# Run command in emacs, get output in clickable buffer

Tags: c++, emacs, buffer, clickable, glimpse

I would like to run a shell command and get its output in clickable buffer in emacs. The command is a shell script that eventually runs glimpse on bunch of source files. Its output looks like grep's output. It includes file name and line number. I would like to be able to click on a file or enter while standing on it and for emacs to take me to that line in the file.
I suppose I need some custom function to do that, but I am new to emacs so I don't yet know how to program it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>M-x grep</kbd> type in your command instead of the default.

<kbd>M-x apropos</kbd> "grep.*null" finds `grep-use-null-device` if you need to not send "/dev/null"

Comment: This seems like an interesting direction. The problem is that emacs appends /dev/null as last argument to my command. I assume it expects grep to run on some set of files and since my command doesn't include any files in its arguments, it appends /dev/null as a default file.

Comment: <kbd>M-x apropos</kbd> "grep.*null" finds `grep-use-null-device`.

Comment: @event_jr To make it easier for others to find it might make sense to also put the content of that comment directly in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to run the command using `shell-command` <kbd>M-!</kbd>, and changing the output buffer's mode to `compilation-mode` using <kbd>M-x compilation-mode</kbd>.

Yet another alternative is to run the command using <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>. The downside of this is that, Emacs allows only one active compilation buffer by default.